# What does the following Jquery code do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning basic Javascript and Jquery. I was going through some codepen codes and was unable to figure out what the following jquery code does. I removed the code and didn't see any change.
The code is

```
$(window).on("load resize ", function() {
  var scrollWidth = $('.tbl-content').width() - $('.tbl-content table').width();
  $('.tbl-header').css({'padding-right':scrollWidth});
}).resize();
```

link to the code

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JMQqJX
```

Comment: well it seems to adapt the right padding of the header when you resize the window. Try resizing it with/without the code and you'll see

Comment: It sets the `padding-right` value of the element with the class `tbl-header` to be the width of the `.tbl-content` element *minus* the width of the `table` within `.tbl-content`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everytime the windows resizes:  `$(window).on("load resize ", function()`

Defines a width using the difference between the element with class tbl-content and the element with classes tbl-content and class table:

```
 var scrollWidth = $('.tbl-content').width() - $('.tbl-content table').width();
```

And then, applies that width result to the css of the class tbl-header in the element padding-right :

```
$('.tbl-header').css({'padding-right':scrollWidth});
```